# How do I remotely run selenium tests on a win xp?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I have a .NET selenium project that is run daily to test our web application. So it has come to our attention that some of our users still use IE8 and IE7 and are not willing to upgrade. I can't install old IE on my development environment since I can only have one version of IE installed. Therefore, we set up another 2 old computers with with IE7 and IE8 installed. Now I can take my selenium project into those computers and run tests on them. But I feel like there must be a better way of running the test from my development computer remotely. I looked into selenium RC and Grid documentation but I got really confused on where to really start. Can anyone please let me know how I can implement this for a .NET Selenium WebDriver application. Or if it is even possible to use Selenium RC (its the new backward compatible version of RC btw) to achieve what I want to do. Any suggestion you make is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be easy. Install a Java runtime environment on the remote machines, and use the Java Selenium standalone server. You can use the `RemoteWebDriver` class in the .NET bindings to run the tests remotely.

To "install" the Java remote WebDriver server, simply download `selenium-standalone-server-2.xx.x.jar` from the [project's download site](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) to the remote machine. On the remote machine, launch the server with `java -jar C:\path\to\selenium-standalone-server-2.xx.x.jar`, substituting the actual path and file name in your command line.

On your local machine, create your WebDriver instance by doing something like the following:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
    new Uri("http://remote-machine-name:4444/wd/hub",
    DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
```

Comment: I am trying to use RemoteWebDriver but I can't manage to get it to work. I am having difficulty setting up the remote web driver

Comment: Updated my answer with more detail. If that doesn't work for you, I suggest you post a question to one of the user-facing mailing lists for the project, found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users) or [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/webdriver)